# Siri will not give me directions home, or recognise my home address correctly

Tags: contacts, siri, maps

I used to be able to ask Siri to 'give me directions home', but this has stopped working a couple of years ago.  Here are the details:

- When I type 'home' into Maps, it picks up the address correctly for my contact card and shows it on the map, and gives directions to it correctly.
- And when I ask Siri 'what is my home address' or 'show me my home address', she opens my contact card and correctly displays my home address.
- But when I ask her to 'show my home address on the map', she replies 'I couldn't find an address for Home'.
- And when I ask her to 'give me directions home', she says 'Hmm... I can't seem to access that data right now. Can you try again in a little while?.'

If I change the address on my contact card to just the street, Siri works fine, but directs me to another house in the street, not my address. And, of course, then the address on my contact card is wrong/incomplete.

The problem is the same on my iPhone, iPad and Mac. It does not appear to be a problem with my devices, since the responses are reproducible on other Macs.  It seems to be a problem with the ability of Siri to find my home address.

I have spent many hours with Apple support who recognise that there is a problem, take data dumps and promise to get back to me, and then after some months it all goes quiet with no further response.

Does anyone have any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: <rant>Maps works on 'postcode', not the actual location of the property. It's been rubbish for years in some locations. I used to have an address in Coventry, UK I went to a lot. Maps would show it in the right place… then navigate to somewhere 5 miles away.</rant>

Comment: I haven't been there in years, but just tested it… still totally wrong, green pin is the correct location (from Contacts), blue line is the navigation - https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4s0i.png

Comment: I got this response from Siri twice earlier this year. Both times it was navigating to a colleague's home. No problems navigating via Siri to my home or to other addresses, and I could manually navigate to his home. Problem eventually went away, but returned. For me it was fixed by exporting his contact card on mac, deleting his Contact card on iPhone, restarting device, and re-importing it on my mac. Hasn't cropped up since.